# What is the value of this?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what 'this' is referencing in my last function (Mamamal.prototype.haveBaby);

```
var Mammal = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.offspring = [];
};

// var myMammal = new Mammal('Joe');

Mammal.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  return 'My name is ' + this.name + ", I'm a Mammal";
};

Mammal.prototype.haveBaby = function(){
  debugger;
  var childName = "Baby " + this.name;
  baby = new this.constructor(childName); //new Cat OR new Mammal
  baby.name = childName;
  this.offspring.push(baby);
  return baby;
};
```

I am not sure why the syntax

```
baby - new this.constructor(childName);
```

is `this` Mammal.prototype?(then constructor so it would be `Mammal.prototype.constructor(childName);` That's the only way I know how to set the constructor.  Mammal.constructor wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` depends on **how** a function is called, in your case `Mammal.prototype.haveBaby`.

If you call it with `Mammal.prototype.haveBaby()`, then `this` refers to `Mammal.prototype`.

If you call it as instance methods (which is more likely), e.g.

```
var mammal = new Mammal(); 
var baby = mammal.haveBaby();
```

then `this` refers to `mammal`.

---

But in both cases you are accessing the *same* property, since every instance of `Mammal` inherits the properties of `Mammal.protoype`. So `this.constructor === Mammal.prototype.constructor`, no matter in which situation of those two.

---

[Read the MDN documentation for more information about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).